# Android Process Viewer

Tags: android, eclipse, cpu

Is there a GUI addon for Eclipse that displays real-time processes/threads and how much CPU they use? Why do I want this? Because I have an service (an IntentService) that uses Thread.sleep() and I want to verify that battery life is preserved.

Comment: If you're creating some sort of long-term recurring behavior, don't use Thread.sleep(), use an AlarmManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html -- even if you're sleeping your service is still resident and using memory.

Answer (score 1):

The DDMS perspective is part of ADT. Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> DDMS.

It should have a Devices window that lists connected devices and whatever apps you can debug. Select your app then press Update Threads (white arrows at the top). The Threads window should list all threads. If you double click one, you can see what it was doing at the time of the click.

Click Start Method Profiling, when you Stop Method Profiling you'll get a break down of what thread was doing what over the duration the Method Profiling was enabled.

Comment: What I need is a chart of the CPU or battery for threads/services as time goes by.

Comment: There may be 3rd party plugins that do this, but the closest I know about is the Method Profiling - which will give you a graph of Thread activity (CPU usage) over time